# How to display output with two digits of precision

Tags: ruby

Here is my code

```
class Atm

  attr_accessor :amount, :rem, :balance

  TAX = 0.50

  def transaction

    @rem = @balance=2000.00
    @amount = gets.chomp.to_f

    if @amount%5 != 0 || @balance < @amount
      "Incorrect Withdrawal Amount(not multiple of 5) or you don't have enough balance"
    else
      @rem = @balance-(@amount+TAX)
      "Successful Transaction"
    end
  end
end

a=Atm.new
puts "Enter amount for transaction"
puts a.transaction
puts "Your balance is #{a.rem.to_f}"
```

and my output is

```
Enter amount for transaction
100                              # user enters this value
Successful Transaction
Your balance is 1899.5
```

as you can see the output, 'Your balance is 1899.5' only displays one digit of precision. I need help to understand and fix the issue. I want two digits of precision in the output.

And also how can I improve this code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this:

```
puts "Your balance is #{'%.02f' % a.rem}"
```

But remember that this code will round your result if you have more than 2 decimal places. Ex.: 199.789 will become 199.79.

Comment: Thank you MurifoX, I would also like to know if I could improve my code in any way? remove any unnecessary code or anything like that?

Comment: Your code is good. Just need to separate the logic into small pieces of code so other people can understand it better. Remember that if the answer was helpful, you can always accept it to help other people.

Comment: Does the leading "0" in front of "2" have a special meaning here?

Comment: @sschuberth Not really. Just to show that it can have big numbers.

Answer (score 8):

It's a fundamental design flaw to store money as a floating point number because floats are inexact. Money should always be stored as an integer in the smallest unit of currency.

Imagine two accounts with 1.005. Display them both, and suddenly there is an extra penny in the world.

Instead store the amount of money in an integer. For example, $1 would be `balance = 100` or 100 pennies. Then format the displayed value:

```
money = 1000
"%.2f" % (money / 100.0)
# => 10.00
```

Comment: It makes sense, I will surely remember this. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge with me.

Comment: can i convert it into the float without losing the 2 zeros at the end

Comment: @user4965201 that doesn't make any sense. A float is a number, and we can agree 5.0 and 5.00 is the same number. When you display 5.0 on a website, you need to convert from number to string, as a number is an abstract concept and needs to be communicated via human language, in this case text.

Comment: Yes, floating point numbers can get wierd. Instead of integers, I find it easier to use `BigDecimal` http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 7):

```
number_with_precision(value, :precision => 2)
```

Should work in Rails

Comment: Hi! Anthony, I am not onto rails yet, have just started learning ruby but I appreciate your response, will remember this code.